# Commands out of sync error; you can't run this command right now

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
DELIMITER $$  
use test;

CREATE PROCEDURE `fn_split_string`(
  p_string    longtext,
    p_delimiter longtext
    )

    BEGIN

select * from(
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1|2|5|6', '|', c+1), '|', -1) as name
    from(
        SELECT (TWO_1.SeqValue + TWO_2.SeqValue + TWO_4.SeqValue + TWO_8.SeqValue + TWO_16.SeqValue + TWO_32.SeqValue) c
        FROM (
            SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 1 SeqValue) TWO_1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 2 SeqValue) TWO_2
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 4 SeqValue) TWO_4
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 8 SeqValue) TWO_8
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 16 SeqValue) TWO_16 
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 32 SeqValue) TWO_32
    ) as b
    WHERE c <= (CHAR_LENGTH('1|2|5|6') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('1|2|5|6', '|', '')))
) as a

   END $$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `use test;` has to be out side the DELIMITER

Further You missed a semicolon behind the  `) a`

```
use test;
DELIMITER $$  


    CREATE PROCEDURE `fn_split_string`(
      p_string    longtext,
        p_delimiter longtext
        )
    
        BEGIN
    
    select * from(
        select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1|2|5|6', '|', c+1), '|', -1) as name
        from(
            SELECT (TWO_1.SeqValue + TWO_2.SeqValue + TWO_4.SeqValue + TWO_8.SeqValue + TWO_16.SeqValue + TWO_32.SeqValue) c
            FROM (
                SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 1 SeqValue) TWO_1
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 2 SeqValue) TWO_2
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 4 SeqValue) TWO_4
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 8 SeqValue) TWO_8
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 16 SeqValue) TWO_16 
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 32 SeqValue) TWO_32
        ) as b
        WHERE c <= (CHAR_LENGTH('1|2|5|6') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('1|2|5|6', '|', '')))
    ) as a;
    
   END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But as you have only one command in your procedure

you can simply write, obly when you use more than 1 command and some other comands leke SET IF THEN you need a DELIMITER

```
use testdb;
CREATE PROCEDURE `fn_split_string`(
  p_string    longtext,
    p_delimiter longtext
    )
    
select * from(
    select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1|2|5|6', '|', c+1), '|', -1) as name
    from(
        SELECT (TWO_1.SeqValue + TWO_2.SeqValue + TWO_4.SeqValue + TWO_8.SeqValue + TWO_16.SeqValue + TWO_32.SeqValue) c
        FROM (
            SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 1 SeqValue) TWO_1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 2 SeqValue) TWO_2
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 4 SeqValue) TWO_4
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 8 SeqValue) TWO_8
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 16 SeqValue) TWO_16 
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 32 SeqValue) TWO_32
    ) as b
    WHERE c <= (CHAR_LENGTH('1|2|5|6') - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE('1|2|5|6', '|', '')))
) as a;
```